# Remove top space from lstlisting inside tabular

Tags: tables, spacing

I have the following problem.

lstlisting seems to add an extra space before and after the code.

Is there a way to remove it ?

I would like to remove the blank spaces before and after the code : "MATCH (n... "

[image]

```
    \lstset{language=C,
            basicstyle=\small,
            breaklines=true,
            aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

    \begin {table}[!h] 
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{|c || p{14 cm}|}
    \hline
    \bf Plateforme  & \bf Code \\
    \hline                                        
    \hline      
    Neo4J & 
    \begin{lstlisting}
    MATCH (n {name: 1}) return n
    \end{lstlisting}
    \\ \hline     
    Titan & 
    Code B
    \\ 
    \hline                                                                                                                                          
    \end{tabular} 
    \end {table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED.  I can't explain why it works, but it seems to.  I put the listing into `\box0`, and that eliminated the top blank line.  Placing an empty `\mbox` before the `\box0` takes care of the line below (alternately, `\leavevmode`), for some reason that gives the appearance of still being in vertical mode.

I have verified that it works also for listing more than a line long.

To summarize the listing `tabular` entry:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{lstlisting}
MATCH (n {name: 1}) return n
\end{lstlisting}}\mbox{}\box0
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C,
            basicstyle=\small,
            breaklines=true,
            aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\begin {table}[!h] 
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c || p{14 cm}|}
\hline
\bf Plateforme  & \bf Code \\
\hline                                        
\hline      
Neo4J & 
\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{lstlisting}
MATCH (n {name: 1}) return n
\end{lstlisting}}\mbox{}\box0
\\ \hline     
Titan & 
Code B
\\ 
\hline                                                                                                                                          
\end{tabular} 
\end {table}
\end{document}
```

[image]