# How to embed lstlisting in table without much space

Tags: tables, listings

I want to embed code in table like the below photo.

[image]

Firstly, I tried code 1.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
\hline
\begin{lstlisting}
code here ......
\end{lstlisting}
\\ \hline
\begin{lstlisting}
code here ......
\end{lstlisting}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, there is too much space between hline and code.

Then, I tried answer in [Remove top space from lstlisting inside tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304472/remove-top-space-from-lstlisting-inside-tabular).

The space became less than first step. However, there is still much space.

If I want the effect just like picture above, how can I do?

Great thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have options `aboveskip` and `belowskip`. If we set these values to zero, there is still a small space. We can get rid of it by setting *negative* values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
\hline
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=-8pt,belowskip=-12pt]
code here ......
\end{lstlisting}
\\ \hline
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=-8pt,belowskip=-12pt]
code here ......
\end{lstlisting}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found the solution that is similar to yours. Great thanks~